# JS add function to element from script with event as parameter

Tags: javascript, events

I know the title is a little confusing, but i dont know how to explain it better.
Now I have this:

```
<script>
button.onclick=delete;
</script>
```

But I need to send the event generated by onclick event to the function delete.
Something like...

```
<script>
button.onclick=delete(event);
</script>
```

I dont know how to do it.
Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The event will already get passed to the function. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t83fww1q/)

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');

button.onclick = func;

function func(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

You will have to change the function name, because [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is already a keyword in javaScript

Answer (score 0):

use 'this' to refer to the event source:

```
<script>
button.onclick=mydelete(this);

//as noted by the other answer, delete is already a function, so choose your own name
function mydelete(obj){
   //access properties of obj in here
}
</script>
```

or jQuery:

```
<script>
$(button).click(function(){
    var obj=$(this);
    //access obj properties here
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Event` is a default `argument` to a handler.

```js
function deleteFun(e){
  console.log(e)
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick=deleteFun;
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

If you are looking for passing custom value to a handler you can use `.bind()`.

```js
function notify(str){
  console.log(str)
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick=notify.bind(null, "Hello World");
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
```